# Angular 5 CORS PUT error - Failed to Load

Tags: angular, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, aws-api-gateway

I have created a link https://xxxxxxx.execute-api.us-west-2.amazonaws/test using
 API gateway for DynamoDB. I have enabled CORS on aws side.

When I try to get the data it works.
When i try to put the data it fails with error:

> Failed to load https://xxxxxxx.execute-api.us-west-2.amazonaws/test:
>   Response for preflight has invalid HTTP status code 400.

I am using Angular 5
my code . I have used a private http:Http  in constructor

```
private url= 'https://xxxxxxx.execute-api.us-west-2.amazonaws/test';

let headers = new Headers({ 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' }); 
headers.append('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
headers.append('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET,PUT,POST,DELETE');

 this.http.put(this.url, JSON.stringify(bodyObj),{headers:headers }) 
    .subscribe(response =>{
    console.log(response.json()) ;
    });
```

Please help .

Comment: headers.append('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET','PUT','POST','DELETE'); are you doing like this or not?

Comment: The CORS headers must be specified **server** side, not client-side like what you posted. Are they configured correctly server side?

Comment: I have set CORS on server. If I use postman to do a put , it works. Only using angular code it gives error.

Comment: I disabled CORS on chrome browser using -disable-web-security . Now its working from that browser only.   Any guess what to do next  ?

Answer (score 0):

Error came because of CORS.

Solution.
- Set OPTIONS as a MOCK ENDPOINT
- Enable CORS again
- Re-Deploy the API
- Dont pass any headers in the angular code.

Now i am not getting any errors.